# Install Ubuntu to a discrete drive without touching the main bootloader

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

My machine is set up as follows:

- `/dev/sda` (i.e. "disk1") - 500GB SSD with my production OS environment on it
- `/dev/sdb` (i.e. "disk2") - a 250GB ssd that I use for storing data files
- `/dev/sdc` (i.e. "disk3") - a 16GB m.sata drive that I only recently found out was installed on my machine, but appears to be a reasonably high performance device (i.e. suitable to run an OS and lightweight apps)

What I'd like to do is install Ubuntu on the 16GB drive so that I can boot into it when needed, but primarily use the `/dev/sda` operating system.

I do NOT want to touch the bootloader on `/dev/sda`. I do NOT need to be able to select the boot device from GRUB or a windows bootloader.  I'm perfectly willing to do an explicit boot device selection from BIOS to choose when I need to boot into the Ubuntu OS on the 16G drive.  I should actually consider this a requirement, as at some point I will likely need to move one or both of these devices to another machine and I want them to appear as standalone devices, each with their native bootloaders and no knowledge of the "other" OS installed on that machine.

I've tried stepping through the Ubuntu installation program, but it's not clear to me how I could do this (both selecting the destination device for the install and ONLY installing grub on that device).  Anyone have suggestions on how this might work?  I found a suggestion that was basically "take the other disks out, install, and then reinstall the disks" but that's not only pretty un-elegant, it's a real pain for me to take this particular machine (laptop) apart to get to the physical drives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the installation process, you are asked to install a bootloader aka grub.

At the bottom of the screen choose the device on which to install it with the drop-down menu.

[image: Choose bootloader location]

That's it.

Although, the installer will certainly auto-detect other OSes and populate the grub menu with it. But that' not a problem. Just ignore those entries.

Answer (score -1):

I know a workaround, might be an easier way though! But previously, I have just installed Ubuntu, installed Grub then used EasyBCD in windows to wipe the entire bootloader, then when you reboot it will take you to the system repair screen. Go to advanced, then use cmd.exe and use the command

```
    bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

This will recreate original Windows Bootloader, which will not find Ubuntu and Grub will not exist. You will now have Ubuntu Alone on your spare disk, which is useless I believe without a bootloader. This is where you would use a livecd like http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/ to install grub to the Ubuntu Disk. But it will try to install grub to the Windows partition, so you will have to specify which disk. Maybe even use Gparted to create a small free partition for for Grub on the Ubuntu disk.

Comment: When you reboot, to run this command, I think you might need to have a windows installation media present in the USB/Disk Drive, but im not sure, its been a while! Either way id have one handy. You would think you wouldn't as recreating the bootloader is easy. But its windows, you never know

Comment: or passing in the original rescue boot of windows (after 3 missing boot or asking to reboot in this mode cfr tons of tutorial for this). It take the bootloader info from installed windows directly (if not dammaged).